# Handling Grammar Ambiguity in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I have a grammar that should parse the following snippet (as an example):

```
vmthread programm_start
{
    CALL main
}

subcall main
{
    // Declarations
    DATAF i

    CALL i

    // Statements
    MOVEF_F 3 i
}
```

The problem is the ambiguity between the CALL statement. This op code is valid in the vmthread section (and only the CALL!) but also in those subcall sections. If I define a OP_CODES token with all op codes and an additional OC_CALL token, the lexer can't handle the situation (obviously).

The following listings are snippets of my grammar (first lexer, second parser):

```
VMTHREAD
    : 'vmthread'
    ;

SUBCALL
    : 'subcall'
    ;

CURLY_OPEN
    : '{'
    ;

CURLY_CLOSE
    : '}'
    ;

OP_CODES
    : 'DATA8'
    | 'DATAF'
    | 'MOVE8_8'
    | 'MOVEF_F'
    | 'CALL'
    ;

OC_CALL
    : 'CALL'
    ;

lms
    : vmthread subcalls+
    ;

vmthread
    : VMTHREAD name = ID CURLY_OPEN vmthreadCall CURLY_CLOSE
    ;

vmthreadCall
    : oc = OC_CALL name = ID
    ;

subcalls
    : SUBCALL name = ID CURLY_OPEN ins = instruction* CURLY_CLOSE
    ;

//instruction+
instruction
    : oc = OP_CODES args = argumentList
    ;

argumentList
    : arguments+
    ;

arguments
    : INTEGER
    | NUMBER
    | TEXT
    | ID
    ;
```

To continue my work I've switched the OC_CALL token in the vmthreadCall parser rule with the OP_CODES token. That solves the problem for now, because the code is auto generated. But there's the possibility that a user can type this code so this could go wrong.

Is there a solution for this or should I move the validation into the parser. There I can easily determine if the statement in the vmthread section contains just the call statement.

**For clarification:** In the vmthread there's only the CALL allowed. In the subcall (could be more than one) every op code is allowed (CALL + every other op code defined). And I do not want to distinguish between those different CALL statements. I know that's not possible in a context free grammar. I will handle this in the parser. I just want to restrict the vmthread to the one CALL statement and allow all statements (all op codes) in the subcalls. Hopefully that's more clear.

Comment: Your question is unclear, because you have not told us the *intended* rules, just that you have produced a grammar that you think matches  the intentions.  Is "CALL" allowed in both subroutines?  Are you trying to distinguish a CALL in the vmthread from the call in the subcall? (You can't do that in a context-free grammar [like ANTLR]).

Comment: @IraBaxter I wrote some text for clarification ("CALL" is allowed in both subroutines and I do not want to distinguish the different CALLs).

Comment: OK.  YOu said CALL was ambiguous.   What's your evidence?

Comment: Not quite sure if ambiguous is the right word. There are two CALL statements in the lexer (OP_CODES and OC_CALL). If OP_CODES is the first token in the lexer it get's matched and the other way round. So in one case the CALL statement in vmthread get's matched with OC_CALL but the CALL statement in the subroutines not and again the other way round. Not quite sure how I can change those rules.

Comment: I suggest you separate out tokens for 'DATA8', 'DATAF', ... rather than clumping them into a single lexing rule.   Then your *grammar* can specify which keywords are allowed without confusion.  (A tricker hack: just pull 'CALL' out of OP_CODES and then fix the grammar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your lexer rules like this:

```
OP_CODES
    : 'DATA8'
    | 'DATAF'
    | 'MOVE8_8'
    | 'MOVEF_F'
    | OP_CALL
    ;

OC_CALL
    : 'CALL'
    ;
```

or alternatively so:

```
OP_CODES
    : 'DATA8'
    | 'DATAF'
    | 'MOVE8_8'
    | 'MOVEF_F'
    | CALL
    ;

OC_CALL
    : CALL
    ;

fragment CALL: 'CALL';
```

Btw, I recommend that you create explicit lexer rules for your literals (like that CALL fragment), which will make later processing easier. ANTLR assigns generic names to implicitly created literals, which makes it hard to find out which token belongs to which literal.

Comment: So I should create lexer rules for every op code? Until now I'm using a parser rule like this: oc = OP_CODES args = arguments newlines to have access via the oc parameter. Are explicit lexer rules still an improvement?

Comment: Yes, I would create a lexer rule for each literal. You can then later access them via known enums (derived from the lexer rule name). The way it is here will give you some autogenerated names and you will have a hard time to find out which was used for which literal.